# Ramsey Numbers with 3 Variables

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Define $R(m,n,k)$ and show that $R(3; 3; 3) = 17$

How would I solve this? I am slowly starting to wrap my head around 2 variable ramsey numbers but not quite on 3. Here I know that R(m,n,k) are vertexes which mean there are 17 vertices and that there are 3 different colored edges. And each of these colors create a monochromatic triangle of the m,n,k colors on a graph. How would I go about showing R(3,3,3) = 17.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: This may be useful https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Combinatorics/Bounds_for_Ramsey_numbers#A_Multicolour_Example:_R(3,3,3)_=_17

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I read through it however i found it quite difficult to comprehend.